# Transfering files based on their names using power shell

Tags: regex, file, powershell, transfer

Our source location having two types of files in its disposal, in terms of their name. First one starts with `DM_psedocharge_<curentdate in YYYYMMDD format>.csv` and other one as `Monthly_Extract_<curentdate in YYYYMMDD format>.csv`.

Now the requirement states that first file shall transfer to target folder  `C:\DMRelated` and second will move to `C:\MonthlyExtract` folder. Both cases the source folder is common.

I tried to capture the right file based on reg es expression within a if condition. If the condition mathes `"^DM_"` then MOVE to `C:\DMRelated` else MOVE to `C:\MonthlyExtract`. But the expression that I have chosen seems to be not right. Can any one please help me on this? I am new on scripting Power Shell.

Comment: hi Nilanjan, please provide a sample code and the error message / details about the misbehaviour your code does.

Comment: There is no error but the condition for matching the pattern is not satisfied. For instance I have used$source = "E:\welcom\SHOP\DEVIBM\Data\Exports\MovementUpdateToDebtManager\Out"
$destination = "E:\Nianjan" 

if(-not (Test-Path $destination)) { mkdir $destination | out-null}
$pattern = "(^DM_*)"

foreach ($i in Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Recurse)
{
    if (($i.Name -notmatch $pattern) -and (-not $i.PsIsContainer))
    {
        Write-Host "Test"
        continue;
    }
   
    Copy-Item -Path $i.FullName -Destination $i.FullName.Replace($source,$destination).Trim($i.Name)
}

Answer (score 1):

Since you're always looking for the current date, you don't need pattern matching - *you already know the exact name of the file!*

```
Set-Location "C:\source\location"
Move-Item "DM_psedocharge_$(Get-Date -Format yyyyMMdd).csv" -Destination C:\DMRelated
Move-Item "Monthly_extract_$(Get-Date -Format yyyyMMdd).csv" -Destination C:\MonthlyExtract
```

In the example above we use the `Get-Date` cmdlet (which defaults to the current date and time) with the `-Format` parameter to get a formatted date string in the form `yyyyMMdd`

Comment: Thanks Mathias for your reply. But situation may arise that in future, the files starts with DM_psedocharge.. may include other pattern as part of its file name dynamically. like appending agreement number. Then the name might get as DM_pseodocharge_1233_<Current DATE in YYYYMMDD format>. That is why I am looking forward for the reg ex. The starting prefix will not change that is for sure.

Comment: You still don't need a regex for that - simple wildcard globbing will suffice: `"DM_psedocharge*_$(Get-Date -Format yyyyMMdd).csv"` (notice the `*`)

Comment: Mathias, thanks for your prompt reply. That is true but what if the date format is changed from yyyyMMdd to yyyyMMddHHmmss. We don't have any control on the HHmmss part of the file generation. I mean we cannot predict the HHmmss on -Format as files are already generated.The stated issue could be resolved by regex. I believe we will come up with better idea..

Comment: @NilanjanSaha still no need for regex: `"DM_psedocharge*_$(Get-Date -Format yyyyMMdd)*.csv"`

Comment: is it suitable to move any file starting with `"DM_psedocharge_"`? if so you could use `Move-Item "DM_psedocharge_*.csv" -Destination C:\DMRelated` and `Move-Item "Monthly_extract_*.csv" -Destination C:\MonthlyExtract` and ignore the date completely. if this is not a possible solution: will the date always be the last part of the file and always be separated by an underscore?

Comment: Extremely, sorry for my late response. @Mathias -> Yes, it is working!! Thanks. Guenther : Thanks for your response, yes date part and underscore is mandatory. The trick that Mathias suggested is fulfilling my purpose.

Comment: @NilanjanSaha that's great to hear, your most welcome!